# How to make linked dropdown list in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet, where there is a list of user names (collected in a dropdown list) and each user is having their own columns and rows. How can I make a dropdown if when a user name is clicked or selected in the dropdown the sheet jumps to corresponding data table of the user.

Comment: You need scripting.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

As [@Harun25hr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr) mentioned in the comments this is feasible via [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

This is a quick sample of how this can be achieved.

Imagine that the data is like this.

[image: Sample Data]

The steps are:

0. Create a new script via `Extensions > Apps Script`
1. Control all changes on the sheet via [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
2. Control with an object the position of the tables
3. Control that the event is only fired when the drop-down list is clicked.
4. Activate the range where the table is.

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
/* CONTROL THE POSITION WITH AN OBJECT */
const position = {
  "WINDOWS": "E1",
  "LINUX": "D1",
  "MAC": "F1"
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const { value, range } = e
  /* CONTROL THE EVENT ONLY FIRES WHEN IS IN THE LINKED LIST */
  if (range.getA1Notation() === "A1") {
    /* MOVE THE SHEET TO THE DESIRED POSITION */
    sS.getRange(position[value]).activate()
  }
}
```

As I said this is just an example and should be adapted to the individual needs of your sheet.

I recommend that you review the Apps Scripts guide on Google Sheets to begin to understand how it works.

###### Documentation

- [Google Sheets and Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [`activate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate)
- [`Event Object`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)